# Service running as Local Admin always writes to sysWOW64

Tags: vb.net, service

I have a service written in VB.NET that is running under the Local System account.

I use the following code to write to a log file:

```
 Dim logDirectory As String = Settings.baseDirectory
 If Settings.loggingDirectory <> "\" Then
       logDirectory &= Settings.loggingDirectory
 End If
 moFileStream = New FileStream(logDirectory & "Log.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)
 moStreamWriter = New StreamWriter(moFileStream)
 moStreamWriter.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End)

 moStreamWriter.Write(Now.ToLongDateString & vbTab & Now.ToLongTimeString & vbTab & sTekst & ControlChars.NewLine)
 moStreamWriter.Flush()
```

Where the baseDirectory and the loggingDirectory are both parameters that are read from a config file. These are read correctly and when i debug, logDirectory holds the correct location.

But when the service writes to the log file, it always writes to sysWOW64. I have tested this on server machines with several permissions to the folder. Even gave everyone full permisions, but for some reason it keeps on writing to sysWOW64.

Is there anybody who has an idea what this could be?

Comment: Clearly the logDirectory is not what you hope it is, it is an empty or null string.  Using "baseDirectory" for the logging file when you also have a "loggingDirectory" setting makes very little sense.  The settings should *not* have Scope=User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, close your `StreamWriter`!

Second, try putting a breakpoint on the `moFileStream = New FileStream` line and check what does `logDirectory` equal to at runtime.

Also, it is worth mentioning, that you don't really need to use the extra `FileStream`. you can just specify the path when creating a new `StreamWriter`. See: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5f5x7kt(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5f5x7kt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Personally, I rarely use the `FileStream`, because it is too complicated and there is no real reason to make things overly complicated. Typically, the more complicated things get, the more are the chances that there is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

The `filestream` and `streamwriter` were created at `OnStart`.
For some reason this made the service unable to write to the log files.